# Testing a Retry bloc using Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, endpoint

I'm trying to write tests for a fail over endpoint mechanism. The intended functionality of the function is to make a call to the primary endpoint, if it succeeds then don't retry, but if it fails then retry 3 times. If it fails after the 3rd attempt then repeat the same with the secondary endpoint.

```
def function
 with_retries(<fill params like handler, max tries etc>) do 
   call primary endpoint
  end
 rescue errors
  with_retries(<fill params like handler, max tries etc>) do 
   call secondary endpoint
  end
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Did you implement `with_retires` or do you use a gem? If it is a gem I would argue that you should not test gem behavior that is already tested within the gem. Then it should be enough the ensure that `with_retires` is actually used in this context.

Comment: @spickermann i did use a custom module that implements ```with_retries```. I'm testing the behaviour of the custom module seperately, but I'm still lost on if I should test this function here because I still want to make sure the secondary endpoint get's called in case the primary fails after all retries. what do you think?

Comment: Testing that the secondary endpoint gets called when the primary returns an error all the time seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `with_retires` method does not need to be tested in this context because it is already tested separately. But IMHO it is reasonable to test that the secondary endpoint is called when the first endpoint returns an error.

Assuming our method looks like this

```
def function
  with_retries(<fill params like handler, max tries etc>) do 
    call_primary_endpoint
  end
rescue errors
  with_retries(<fill params like handler, max tries etc>) do 
    call_secondary_endpoint
  end 
end
```

then I would write an RSpec expectation like this

```
describe "#function" do
  subject { YourClass.new }

  before do
    # no need to test the actually endpoint implementation, we are only interested in the behavior
    allow(subject).to receive(:call_primary_endpoint).and_raise("ExpectedError")
    allow(subject).to receive(:call_secondary_endpoint).and_return(:expected_result)
  end

  it "calls secondary endpoint when the primary fails" do
    subject.function

    # Test that the primary endpoint is called max retry times (I assume 3 times)
    expect(subject).to have_received(:call_primary_endpoint)..exactly(3).times
    # Test that the secondary endpoint is called once
    expect(subject).to have_received(:call_secondary_endpoint).once
  end
end
```